# How to deactivate button once clicked

Tags: php

How to write code to activate and deactivate button using PHP....for example if one clicked the button it should disbled and it should not be available for any other users until it is enabled by user who disabled it

How can I convert button to true or false when clicked

Comment: You should give the more information and write some code what did you do to achieve that goal.

Comment: use js - if you want to store the value use super global - if you want to store the value for a looong time use a database

Comment: You need to use javascript or jquery to enable to disable button.

Comment: There are a couple of comments suggesting using JS instead. Read the question more carefully, it says **should not be available for any other users**. Sharing data between different users requires *server-side code*. While you could use server-side JavaScript for this (although jQuery would not be helpful), the OP has selected PHP. Recommendations to use JS aren't massively helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want this even if the user leaves the browser, then you need to store ( in a database, .json file, .ini file, .yaml file etc ) the user who clicked the button and the button's current state. And check your storage each time for the state of the button when page is loaded.

You don't need javascript for this. If using a .php file you can do this based on the button's state:

```
<?php if( $button_state === false ): ?>
    <button disabled> button </button>
<?php else: ?>
    <button> button </button>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: You could even do `<button <?php if( $button_state === false ): ?>disabled<?php endif; ?>>Button Text</button>`